# Saferpay Implementation

Tags: payment-gateway

I am implementing Saferpay gateway. But the problem is whenever I am sending USD 5.25 as the amount it is saying : attribute AMOUNT is not numeric.
I am very confused because of that, can any one help me regarding this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have to convert this amount to cents:

5.25 * 100 = 525.

That's the case with most of the payment gateways...

Comment: so how wil that be calculated as 5.25 USD?

Comment: From the docs: AMOUNT  The amount to be reserved specified in minor currency unit. E.g. 
EUR 1.35 must be passed as 135. 
CURRENCY  Specifies the transaction currency with a string ISO 4217 
currency code, e.g. EUR, CHF, USD etc.

Comment: https://www.bs-card-service.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Dokumente/E-Commerce_Mailorder/Web-Terminal_Downloads/Saferpay_Implementation_Guide_v1.62.pdf